# How do I get Pidgin to authorize for Facebook?

Tags: pidgin

How can I get Pidgin to connect to my Facebook chat? It says UserName@chat.facebook .com/disabled
Not Authorized ...

Please help, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook changed its API and messaging protocol in 2015, thus XMPP applications are no longer able to connect:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

You can try another native client:

https://github.com/Aluxian/Facebook-Messenger-Desktop

(Personally, I recommend version 2.0.2.)